# HTTP Live Streaming on Android 2.x, is NDK the only way to go

Tags: android, http, video, streaming, live

I am working on an app that needs to render video streaming using the HTTP Live Streaming protocol. From what  I read it is only supported on Android 3.0(Does 2.3 support it too?). My question is for 2.1 and 2.2 phones, are there any other ways than developing a library using NDK? Has anyone used the Nexstream SDK? Please pointing out some directions, be NDK or available 3rd party SDK.

Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, there 3rd party libraries. Akamai's library is fairly good.